# Definir uma propriedade dentro de um BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Salve galera!

Estou trabalhando com c# MongoDB .Net Driver, e tem algo que não estou entendendo nas consultas, segue o exemplo:

```
    var dataBase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
    var transactionsColl = dataBase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(transactionCollectionName);

    var mongoSales = transactionsColl.Aggregate()
                            .Match(BsonDocument.Parse("{ 'saleDate': { $lte: ISODate('" + timeStamp.ToString("o") + "') } }"))
                            .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$saleId" }, { "_documentObjId", "$_id" } }).ToListAsync().Result;
```

No agrupamento tenho `{ "_id", "$saleId" }` e `{ "_documentObjId", "$_id" }`, o erro está no `"_documentObjId"`, causa a seguinte exception:

```
{"Command aggregate failed: the group aggregate field '_documentObjId' must be defined as an expression inside an object."}
```

Eu tinha entendido que poderiar colocar qualquer nome como propriedade do documento, mas pelo erro não é tão simples assim, inclusive no `"_id"` se eu alterar para qualquer outro nome da o mesmo erro, onde eu faço essa definição?
Valeu!

Comment: Olá, Eu não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta. Mas acredito que você o erro ocorre é porque você não mapeou o campo _documentObjId em lugar algum. Você já conseguiu avançar?

Comment: @Jhonathan, em resumo é isso, não entendi onde consigo fazer esse mapeamento, visto que o _id eu também não fiz o mapeamento, mas funciona.

Comment: Você criou uma classe para tratar os objetos? Seria melhor utilizá-la ao invés de BsonDocument.

Comment: @Jhonathan pesquisei sobre isso antes, mas abandonei por conta da performance, segundo relatos a performance cai muito assim, e esse serviço que estou criando vai gerar um cubo de dados e por isso preciso de muita performance.

Comment: @Jhonathan , mas se não tiver outra maneira vou ter que criar uma classe mesmo... Mas minha curiosidade a respeito do _id funcionar sem mapear vai ficar.

Comment: Bom minhas dicas são: Tente testar este código no mongoDB, pode ser que sua agregação esteja montada errada. Tente remover o (underline) da variável documentObjId

Comment: @Jhonathan, fiz como você falou, deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36510/discussion-between-jhonathan-and-rhgm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendi a sintaxe:

```
var mongoSales = transactionsColl.Aggregate()
                        .Match(BsonDocument.Parse("{ 'saleDate': { $lte: ISODate('" + timeStamp.ToString("o") + "') } }"))
                        .Group(new BsonDocument { {"_id", new BsonDocument { { "document", "$document" }, { "saleDate", "$manticSaleDate" } } } }).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Tenho que criar um novo BsonDocument (_id) e dentro dele posso agrupar por quantos fields quiser e nele defino os nomes dos fields. Obrigado pela tentativa em ajudar @Jhonathan. :)